# XSL parsing and sorting by date

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing

I have this existing xsl that is used in rendering an RSS feed.
Besides the title, everything else is parsed out from the description field.
The snippet below is how it is being done at the moment. It works but there is no set ordering of the items.
How do I modify what I have so the items are sorted by `itemPubDate`.
A sample `itemPubDate` value is `06/26/2013`.

```
<xsl:template name="RSSMainTemplate.body">
    <xsl:param name="Rows" />
    <xsl:param name="RowCount" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
        <xsl:variable name="CurPosition" select="position()" />
        <xsl:variable name="RssFeedLink" select="$rss_ID" />
        <xsl:variable name="CurrentElement" select="concat($RssFeedLink,$CurPosition)" />
        <xsl:call-template name="RSSDescTransform1">
            <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionField" select="description" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="RSSDescTransform1">
    <xsl:param name="DescriptionField" />
    <xsl:variable name="itemTitle" select="title" />
    <xsl:variable name="itemAuthor" select="substring-before(substring-after($DescriptionField, 'itemAuthor:&lt;/b&gt; '),'&lt;/div&gt;')" />
    <xsl:variable name="itemPubDate" select="substring-before(substring-after($DescriptionField, 'itemPubDate:&lt;/b&gt; '),'&lt;/div&gt;')" />
    <xsl:variable name="itemDescription" select="substring-before(substring-after($DescriptionField, 'itemDescription:&lt;/b&gt; '),'&lt;/div&gt;')" />
    <xsl:variable name="itemHTML" select="substring-after($DescriptionField, 'itemHTML:&lt;/b&gt; ')" />
    <xsl:variable name="itemLink" select="substring-before(substring-after($DescriptionField, 'href=&quot;'),'&quot;')" />
    <xsl:call-template name="RSSDescTransform2">
        <xsl:with-param name="itemTitle" select="$itemTitle" />
        <xsl:with-param name="itemAuthor" select="$itemAuthor" />
        <xsl:with-param name="itemPubDate" select="$itemPubDate" />
        <xsl:with-param name="itemDescription" select="$itemDescription" />
        <xsl:with-param name="itemLink" select="$itemLink" />
        <xsl:with-param name="itemHTML" select="$itemHTML" /></xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Full XSL [**here**](http://pastebin.com/UGce5hJ7)

I currently don't have a sample for the input, but it looks something like

```
<item>
  <title>lorem ipsum</title>
  <description>
    <![CDATA[
      <div>
        itemAuthor:<b>John</b>
        itemPubDate:<b>06/26/2013</b>
        ...
      </div>
    ]]>
  <description>
</item>
<item>
  ...
</item>
```

The output is pretty much the same, just styled with some CSS.

---

The XSL right now doesn't cause any errors. I simply want to have the items sorted by `itemPubDate`

Comment: Without an input XML and desire output examples its really hard to say what the problem is. You can use `<xsl:sort>` with `<xsl:apply-templates>` but not with call, and the fact you have two levels of `<xsl:call-template>` makes me think there are other issues with your XSL.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Added additional information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to apply a sort in your for-each within your RSSMainTemplate.body template.
The key is extracting the date pieces (Year, Month, Day), and sorting on each one individually

```
<xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
       <xsl:sort select="substring(substring-before(substring-after(description, 'itemPubDate:&lt;b&gt;'),'&lt;/b&gt;'),7,4)"  />
       <xsl:sort select="substring(substring-before(substring-after(description, 'itemPubDate:&lt;b&gt;'),'&lt;/b&gt;'),4,2)"  />
       <xsl:sort select="substring(substring-before(substring-after(description, 'itemPubDate:&lt;b&gt;'),'&lt;/b&gt;'),1,2)"  />
```

---

also I noticed an issue in your select statements to extract the information from the div (based on your example XML), where you had

```
<xsl:variable name="itemPubDate" select="substring-before(substring-after($DescriptionField, 'itemPubDate:&lt;/b&gt; '),'&lt;/div&gt;')" />
```

it should be

```
<xsl:variable name="itemPubDate" select="substring-before(substring-after($DescriptionField, 'itemPubDate:&lt;b&gt;'),'&lt;/b&gt;')" />
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! Actually the select statement is correct, I just got the input wrong. It was supposed to look like `<div><b>itemPubDate:</b> 22/07/2013</div>`. I've modified your answer accordingly.